# Responsive SVG rectangle

Tags: html, css, svg

I [found](https://codepen.io/seanmccaffery/pen/xBpbG) a very good example of svg button animation but the size of the button is static - 320px x 60px. I would like to have the button responsive - it is svg rectangle, but I struggle to achieve that.

HTML:

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg class="svg-responsive" viewBox="0 0 320 60" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect class="shape" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="text">HOVER</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.svg-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;

  height: 0;
  padding-top: 16.6%;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shape {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: salmon;
  stroke-dasharray: 140 540;
  stroke-dashoffset: -474;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke: #19f6e8;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  line-height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  top: -48px;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 140 540;
    stroke-dashoffset: -474;
    stroke-width: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 760;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
}

.svg-wrapper:hover .shape {
  -webkit-animation: 0.5s draw linear forwards;
  animation: 0.5s draw linear forwards;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dePNLG

Already read a [tutorial](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/) on the matter and I followed all the steps for inline svg but I guess I'm missing something.
Can you help me get that SVG rectangle responsive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the preserveAspectRatio="none" attribute to your svg